# Kendo UI Charts - Changing marker styling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, kendo-ui

I am trying to style the markers on a Kendo UI Line chart.
I am using the Kendo-Angular bridge which can be found [here](https://github.com/kendo-labs/angular-kendo/).

I've got a simple Line chart which loads data from a JSON file. Using the `k-options` directive I am passing in an object with the styles what I've created. Everything seems to work except the [series.markers API](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/dataviz/chart#configuration-series.markers)

Creating the chart with the angular directives:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="demo-section k-content">
        <div class="box-col" style="width: 500px;">
            <h4>Hover some series</h4>
            <div kendo-chart="chart"
                 k-legend="{ position: 'bottom' }"
                 k-series-defaults="{ type: 'line' }"
                 k-series="[
                                 { field: 'id', name: 'ID' },
                                 { field: 'value', name: 'VALUE' }
                             ]"
                 k-data-source="electricity"
                 k-series-hover="onSeriesHover"
                 k-options="chartOptions"
                 ></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Initializing it:

```
angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives" ]);
function MyCtrl($scope, $interval) {

    $scope.chartOptions = {
        renderAs: "canvas",
        transitions: false,
        //Start widget styling
        categoryAxis:{
            background: '#551A8B'
        },
        seriesColors: ["#fa7839"],
        series: {
            markers: {
                type: "triangle",
                size: 30
            }
        }
    }
    $scope.electricity = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "electricity.json",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        scheme: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    Id: { type: "number" },
                    Value: {type: "number"}
                }
            }
        },
        change: function (data) {
            $scope.chart.redraw()
            console.log(data)
            console.log("Changed")
        }
    });
    // Refresh the graph every 150ms
    $interval(function(){
        $scope.chart.redraw()
        }, 150);


}
```

This code seems to adhere to the examples shown in the API docs. The `categoryAxis` and `seriesColors` work, but the `series.markers.type` and `series.markers.size` do not seem to have any effect. 
What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Series is array option, you should specify those 'markers' option for each separate series. In  your case you have specified it as an option of the series as an object (not array). First option -try to specify it explicitly inside any of the objects inside the array with series.

e.g.

```
k-series="[
            { field: 'id', name: 'ID',
              markers: {
                 type: 'triangle',
                 size: 30
              } 
             },
            { field: 'value', name: 'VALUE' }
          ]"
```

Another option to try is to put that inside the seriesDefault.

Also as explicitly noted in the documentation you have to use series type such as "area", "line", "scatter", "scatterLine", "radarLine", "radarArea", "polarLine", "polarScatter" or "polarArea" in order to have markers. By default the series is of type 'column'.

Comment: Thanks, adding the options to the seriesDefault did the trick. It was already defined as a "line" as a directive. The documentations seems to lack on detail as to where the options should go.